# Django/ReactJS how to add django urls as props?

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

Keep in mind that I am completely fresh with react/django and I need all the help I can get.

I want to create a Navbar component in my application with React. The problem is that the navbar has links to other parts of the application.
What I am trying to do is to pass an array with all the links as props to my navbar component. But how can I get the links in javascript dynamically?

Right now I have this:

index.js:

```
let navbarUrls = [
  {key: 0, url: "{% url 'main:index' %}"}
];

ReactDOM.render(<Navbar urls={navbarUrls} />, document.getElementById('navbar'));
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                   {this.props.urls.map(url => (
                      <a class="navbar-brand" key={url.key} href={url.url}>Main Page</a>
                    ))}
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    </ul>
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <div id="current-time">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

While the elements are created, the links are of course not since it does not recognize twig... Maybe I am doing this completely wrong? Can someone direct me to the right way??

Answer (score 0):

I am working with React and Django. I have faced a similar type of issue.

```
const navbarUrls = [
        {title: 'TAB-1', path: ''},
        {title: 'TAB-2', path: 'tab2'},
        {title: 'TAB-2', path: 'tab3'},
    ];
```

Lat's Assume these are you links

Now Create a navbar component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'; // install react-router and react-router-dom version 4.x

class Navbar extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                   {this.props.navbarUrls.map(link => (
                      <Link to={link.path}>{link.title}</Link>
                    ))}
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    </ul>
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <div id="current-time">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

Now your `index.jsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM 'react-dom';
import {Route, HashRouter, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from 'your-path';


    ReactDOM.render(
       <HashRouter> // you can use BrowserRoute as well.
          <Navbar urls={navbarUrls} />
               <Switch>
                    <Route extact path="/" component={YourComponent1}/>
                    <Route path="/tab2" component={YourComponent2}/>
                    <Route path="/tab2" component={YourComponent2}/>
                </Switch>
        </HashRouter>,
      document.getElementById('app')); //id from your main html page.
```

Please read the doc of `react-router` https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router if you are not familiar with it.